# Карта для игрушки

Tags: javascript

Такой вот вопросик, есть много игрушек на javascript'e, тобишь там можно бегать, как бегать, перемещать картинку своего персонажа по bacground'у. Вот интересно, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста, или скажите статейку на это дело, заранее спасибо)

Comment: Молодой человек, если Вы действительно вчера начали изучать JS, то советую Вам повременить с игрушками. JavaScript это полноценный язык программирования и приступать к его изучению надо основательно. Читать книги и статьи.  А не прыгать с технологии на технологию. Сегодня хочу это, завтра то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу помочь с передвижением блока по экрану на **jQuery**, может это вам чем то поможет:

**CSS:**

```
body{
   background: black;
   font-family: verdana;
   font-size: 12px;  
}
#sqr{
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), to(#dddddd));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
   position: absolute;
   top: 1%;
   left: 1%;
   width: 10%;
   height: 20%;
   border-radius: 6px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px white;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#str{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0%;
}
#vv, #vn, #vl, #vp{
   outline: none;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border: #057ed0 1px solid;
   color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   background: #029bd2;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#32bbef), to(#029bd2));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32bbef, #029bd2);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32bbef, #029bd2);
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Поиграем с квадратиком</title>
<meta charset='window-1251'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jQuery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Квадратик -->
<div id='sqr' width='300'></div>
<!-- END -->

<!-- Стрелки -->
<div id='str' align='center'>
<input type='button' id='vv' value='Вверх'><br />
<input type='button' id='vl' value='Влево'> <input type='button' id='vp' value='Вправо'><br />
<input type='button' id='vn' value='Вниз'><br />
</div>
<!-- END -->

</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var vv = $('#vv'); //Вверх
var vn = $('#vn'); //Вниз
var vl = $('#vl'); //Влево
var vp = $('#vp'); //Вправо
var sqr = $('#sqr'); //Квадратик

var tp = 1;
var rt = 1;

vv.click(function(){
tp = tp - 7;
$('#sqr').animate({'top':tp+'%'},300);   
});

vn.click(function(){
tp = tp + 7;
$('#sqr').animate({'top':tp+'%'},300);   
});

vl.click(function(){
rt = rt - 5;
$('#sqr').animate({'left':rt+'%'},300);   
});

vp.click(function(){
rt = rt + 5;
$('#sqr').animate({'left':rt+'%'},300);   
});

});
```

Код, конечно, далеко от идеального, но это может Вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо >>> Работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы же позавчера начали учить JavaScript, куда вы гонитесь? Прочитайте нормальных книг, да усвойте материал.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам нужен `Canvas`, это `HTML5`. Сейчас уже много игрушек на нем.

Comment: Смотреть в сторону отечественной библиотеки libcanvas.

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть в сторону fabric.js - тоже отечественная :)

Comment: простите конечно, но до three.js ни первая ни вторая не дотягивают :)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, эти ссылки вам помогут.

http://www.pawelch.com/html_create_game
http://habrahabr.ru/post/125857/
http://firstdev.org/post/programmirovanie/uroki/sozdaem-svoyu-pervuyu-igru-na-html5-urok-1/

Answer (score 0):

http://home.onfind.net/

сделана без канваса